# How do I have each click event and rotate the camera on click in "model_viewer_plus" package?

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

How do I have each click event and rotate the camera on click in [model_viewer_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/model_viewer_plus) package?

```dart
ModelViewer(
  backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(0xFF, 0xEE, 0xEE, 0xEE),
  src: 'https://modelviewer.dev/shared-assets/models/Astronaut.glb',
  alt: 'A 3D model of an astronaut',
  cameraControls: true,
  interactionPromptStyle: InteractionPromptStyle.wiggle,
  iosSrc: 'https://modelviewer.dev/shared-assets/models/Astronaut.usdz',
  disableZoom: false,
),
```